# Fresh Server 14.04 install: "Unable to locate package (xyz)" for everything; How do I edit sources.list?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, software-sources

I can't install anything with `apt-get` on my fresh 14.04 Server installation. I get `Unable to locate package [xyz]` for everything I try. `sudo apt-get update` does nothing. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) implies that I need to edit `sources.list`, but I don't know how. I don't think any text editor is installed, as this is the server version.

How do I fix this? My server is rendered useless if I can't install anything.

EDIT: Here's the output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) trusty InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) trusty/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3) trusty/restricted Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Is it supposed to do this?

EDIT 2: There is only one line in `sources.list`:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`? Also could you update your question with `sudo apt-get update` complete output?

Comment: @Letizia - I posted the output of `sudo apt-get update`. I didn't know about vi, so I'll certainly try that.

Comment: Update: It contains only one line. See EDIT 2 in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment, use this as your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://[cc].archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://[cc].archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://[cc].archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main multiverse universe restricted
```

Replace `[cc]` with your country code (such as `us` for the US, `fr` for France, `in` for India). And remove the channels you don't need (one or more of `multiverse`, `universe`, `restricted`).

Comment: It is actually Trusty (should have used "Trusty" instead of the number). Sorry for the inconsistency. I'll try this.

Comment: @Roadsguy :D And I first posted with `trusty`, editing quickly when I noticed the 14.10 after a re-read.

Comment: This worked. I can now install software!

Comment: Editing the source.list in this way worked for me too. Be sure after you make this change to the source.list, you rerun sudo apt-get update (otherwise the changes will not take effect, at least in my experience).